# Angular Kendo-Autocomplete add search icon

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

We have an kendo auto complete search box as shown below[image]
I need to add a search icon inside the search box, I have checked the documentation but I couldn't find any information.

I'm have also tried adding `<span class="k-icon k-i-search"></span>`

```
<div class="mt-75px">
    <kendo-autocomplete [data]="data" [filterable]="true" 
        
        placeholder="search with parma or supplier name">

    </kendo-autocomplete>
    <span class="k-icon k-i-search"></span>
    <div class="ps-center  visible-xs">
        <button kendoButton [primary]="true" type="button" (click)="onSearch()"
           >Search</button>
    </div>


</div>
```

But unable to place it inside the search

Please help me with your suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Do you want search icon at right side but inside kendo input box ? Can you tell your full use case ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Yes, I need search icon inside the input box towards right

Comment: @GRD I could achieve the requirement , Thank you.

Comment: @KiranNarayan let me know further if you need.

Comment: Hi, @KiranNarayan, could you please share solution?